# Can't install Visual Studio NUnit 3 Test Adapter v3.8.0. and above

Tags: visual-studio, nunit

I use Visual Studio 2015 and want to upgrade my old NUnit 2 tests to the newest NUnit version 3.9.0, but I can't install the Visual Studio Test Adapter 3.9.0.

The error message is:

> "Could not install package 'NUnit3TestAdapter 3.9.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v2.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."
>   Installing the plugin until version 3.7.0 works fine, only installing 3.8.0 and 3.9.0 throw errors.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

The 3.9.0 release of the adapter seems to have removed support for .NET 2.0.

You can re-target your tests for .NET 3.5 if that is available to you, keeping the SUT targeted to 2.0. The system you are testing will normally run just as well under 3.5 and that also gives you the ability to use some 3.5 features that make testing easier.

The alternative, of course, is to not upgrade to 3.9. Most new features in the adapter since 3.5 or so shouldn't affect your development under .NET 2.0.